# Why won't this web page finish loading?

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser

If I run this code, why doesn't the page ever finish loading? It will always show connecting on my browser tab.

It is a simple javascript which will prompt an alert box and change the entire document to the word testing.

Javascript - testQuery.js

```
(function (window, undefined) {

var testQuery = function(obj) {
        if (!(this instanceof testQuery)) {
            return new testQuery(obj);
        }
}


testQuery.alertMessage = function () {
        alert("alert");
    document.write("testing");
};

   window.testQuery = testQuery;

}) (window);
```

HTML - testQuery.html

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="testQuery.js"></script>
<script>

function onClick() {

testQuery.alertMessage();

}

</script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 4):

Because you didn't close the document.

[`document.close()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.close)

Comment: @simplified in theory you also need `document.open` but `document.write` opens a new document if the existing document is already closed.

Comment: thanks. but in the sense, in theory, by putting in just making the flow look more complete?